# Dropdown change upon selection

Tags: jquery, html

I have this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Mxkfr/2/

it works but i need to submit the `VALUE` of both drop down to another page for a mysql query. Right now the only way the drop down will work is if the `VALUE` of both are the same.

how can I assign something different for it to match against, instead of `VALUE`

**UPDATE**

after adding my mysql query to the drop down it stops working after the 20th record in the first drop down. It's exactly the 20th. the drop down has 150 records.

http://pastebin.com/rDRcNrGn

I put my code on jsfiddle and pastebin because I don't want it coming up on google.

**UPDATE 2**

after spending hours on this issue i am still unable to figure out what is causing this issue. i've changed my queries and still no luck. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Are you really restricted to jQuery 1.6.4?

Comment: no the issue is I need to name col1-col3 as firstname. then VALUE of the next drop down is lastname. No i am not restricted to that specific version.

Comment: Please include your code in the question instead of just linking to JsFiddle.

Comment: i do it because i dont like having my code showing up in google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not put a class

like so

```
   <option value="whatever value" class="col3">layout 3</option>
    <option value="other value" class="col3">layout 4</option>
    <option value="col3_sms" class="col3">layout 5</option>
```

and then just

```
$('.col3').show()
```

here is a live example

http://jsfiddle.net/JKbjV/1/

Comment: this one worked great!! it allows me to define different VALUE for both drop downs, so that I can use them in the next page separately. Thank you!

Comment: any idea why it would stop working after the 20th selection in the first drop down?

Comment: here is the code http://pastebin.com/G8UJei6A the first drop down works and lists all the robots but if I chose robot 21 on the first drop down the second drop down becomes blank.

Answer (score 1):

I would take a different approach, using `data-` attributes to identify which dropdown selections should be disabled.

HTML:

```
<select name="column_select" id="column_select">
    <option value="1" selected>1 column</option>
    <option value="2">2 column</option>
    <option value="3">3 column</option>
</select>

<select name="layout_select" id="layout_select">
    <!--Below shows when '1 column' is selected is hidden otherwise-->
    <option data-col="1" value="none">none</option>

    <!--Below shows when '2 column' is selected is hidden otherwise-->
    <option data-col="2" value="layout-1">layout 1</option> 
    <option data-col="2" value="layout-2">layout 2</option>

    <!--Below shows when '3 column' is selected is hidden otherwise-->
    <option data-col="3" value="layout-3">layout 3</option>
    <option data-col="3" value="layout-4">layout 4</option>
    <option data-col="3" value="layout-5">layout 5</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#column_select").change(function() {
        var val = $(this).val();
        // not all browsers let you hide individual options; disable them instead
        $("#layout_select").children().prop('disabled',true).filter(function(i) {
                return $(this).data('col')<=val;
            }).prop('disabled',false);
    });
    $('#column_select').trigger('change');
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Mxkfr/88/

Comment: this works great but is it possible to completely hide the other options instead of graying them out?

Comment: Not all browsers let you `display:none` individual options, apparently. You'd have to `.remove()` them, store them in a variable, and add them back if needed.